# C# tree population

Tags: c#, tree

i need to create a tree like using the letters of a string.
for example: BAT the tree will look like this

```
                       #
              /        |      \
              B        A       T
             / \      / \     / \
            A   T    B   T   B   A
            |   |    |   |   |   |
            T   A    T   B   A   B
```

i tried using a recursion..but always showed stack overflow.
Can anyone suggest an efficient algorithm for this.The logic should work for any no of letters.
i have not added my code here because its totally wrong.I am new to programming using data structures.

Given below is the code i have written:

```
                   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Tree_recursion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String str;
            Console.WriteLine("Word : ");
            str = Console.ReadLine();
            str = str + "*";
            int len = str.Length;
            int i=0;
            Char[] letters = new char[len];
            letters = str.ToCharArray();
            Node root = new Node('#');
            Node ret_node=new Node();
            for (int j = 0; j < len;j++ )
            {
                i = j;
                ret_node = root.Addnode(letters[i++]);
            }                                               
        }
    }
    class Node
    {
        public char c;
        public List<Node> Child = new List<Node>();
        public Node()
        {
        }
        public Node(char ch)
        {
            Node n=new Node();
            n.c=ch;
        }
        public Node Addnode(char ch)
        {
            if (ch == '*')
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                Node n1 = Addnode(ch++);
                this.Child.Add(n1);
                return n1;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What does this tree have to contain exactly? All the permutations of 3 letters? Can letters be repeated? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Combinations of letters in the word..

Comment: after populating the tree is read through each branch.to get each of the combinations.I tried a recursion but doesnt work.

Comment: Please add your code even if it's wrong. People expect you to prove that you have tried something. In any case it is a good starting point for improving your code and your skills in programming.

Comment: Do you need the tree structure for some reason, or are you only trying to get all the permutations?

Comment: i need to get the combinations,not the permutations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

First define a tree structure:

```
public class Tree<T>
{
    public T Value { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<Tree<T>> Children { get; private set; }

    public Tree(T value, IEnumerable<Tree<T>> children)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        this.Children = new List<Tree<T>>(children);
    }

    public string Dump()
    {
        return this.Dump(0);
    }

    protected string Dump(int level)
    {
        var query =
            (new [] { "".PadLeft(level, '-') + this.Value.ToString() })
            .Concat(this.Children.Select(x => x.Dump(level + 1)));

        return String.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, query);
    }
}
```

Your node structure made things a little more difficult to work with.

Then you can build a tree like this:

```
var text = "ABC";

Func<IEnumerable<char>, IEnumerable<Tree<char>>> build = null;
build = xs =>
    from x in xs
    select new Tree<char>(x, build(xs.Except(new [] { x })));

var tree = new Tree<char>('#', build(text));
```

The result of running `Dump` on this tree is:

```
#
-A
--B
---C
--C
---B
-B
--A
---C
--C
---A
-C
--A
---B
--B
---A
```

Comment: does this avoid duplication? Each branch should contain a letter only once.

Comment: How to read the tree along each branch,so as to display each combinations of the letters.

Comment: @atm007 - Yes, it avoids duplication. I've created a `Dump` method to view the contents of the tree.